# Can anyone provide simple Netlogo models tha can be easily extended?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I am new to netlogo and I would like to do some excise like extending models in netlogo

I would happy if anyone can provide me some small projects in netlogo that I can afford to edit and extend it in smoothly way ,

Thanks in advance
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds in the NetLogo Models Library, accessible via NetLogo's File menu. Sample Models contain complete (but usually still reasonably small) models, and Code Examples are small demonstrations of individual coding techniques.

There are tons more at http://modelingcommons.org and http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/ .

You might also look at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/resources.shtml which has links to textbooks, tutorials, and other learning resources.